# Is there are way to use the Dropbox API to upload to a single users Dropbox?

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am wondering if there is a way that the Dropbox API can be utilized to grant access rights globally for an app.

Here is my scenario.  I am developing a Java application that will allow a teacher to have his students submit assignments.  The application will perform a plethora of tasks, but then it will upload the file to the teacher's Dropbox account.

I have been able to get the application to authenticate and upload to each specific user's Dropbox/Apps/LabTab folder, but is there a way that I can make it so that the application always connects to the teacher's dropbox and uploads to his Dropbox/Apps/LabTab folder?

I guess an easier way of stating it is to say that I want a way for a user to grant global access to unauthenticated requests from my single application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar in my web application, where project members have common place for documents in project creator/owner dropbox application directory, when he authorizes this application.

You also (probably) should do this on app level.
If Your application is j2se based (desktop application) You'll have to hardcode teacher's access token into application, or (better) do some web interface, which will connect each teacher's access token with teacher's resources (Dropbox/Apps/YoursApplication per teacher).
In this scenario, end users (probably students) will be able to upload/download/act on teachers resources, through yours application AS this concrete teacher.